# Работа с QTimer, QThread и ProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Хочется выполнить вычисления в отдельном от Ui потоке без всяких сигналов. Метод, выполняющий вычисления — это приватный слот главного окна. По окончанию вычислений данные вываливаются в объект `OutputData`, который является полем главного окна. Поток, в котором выполняются вычисления — это тоже поле главного окна.

Конструктор главного окна, где создаётся поток и связывается начала вычислений и старт потока:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    calculation = new QThread(this);

    settings.setToDefault();
    outputData.setToDefault();
    calculationDone = false;

    connect(calculation, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(calculate()));

    ui->results_display->setText("Загрузите <b>параметры</b> и начинайте расчёты!");
}
```

Метод нажатия на кнопку, запускающий поток и модальное окно с ProgressBar:

```
void MainWindow::on_calculate_button_clicked() {
    ui->results_display->clear();
    ui->results_display2->clear();

    calculation->start();

    ///TODO QProgressDialog

    ProgressDialog progressDialog(&outputData, this);
    progressDialog.setModal(true);
    progressDialog.exec();

    if (progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Rejected) {
        calculation->terminate();
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Результат", "Расчёт был остановлен!");
    } else {
        if (progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Accepted) {
            calculation->quit();
            QMessageBox::about(this, "Результат", "Готово!");
        }
    }
}
```

Конструктор модального окна с ProgressBar, где происходит настройка ProgressBar, создание таймера и его связь с обновлением ProgressBar:

```
ProgressDialog::ProgressDialog(OutputData *outputData, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ProgressDialog) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    data = outputData;

    ui->quantity_label->setText("0");
    ui->progressBar->setMinimum(0);
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(static_cast<int>(data->outputSettings.aircraftQuantity));

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(false);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(50);
}
```

Метод, обновляющий информацию ProgressBar'a:

```
void ProgressDialog::update() {

    unsigned long aircraftsDone = data->results.size() + data->unprocessedAircrafts.size();
    ui->progressBar->setValue(static_cast<int>(aircraftsDone));
    ui->aircraftQunatityDone_label->setText(QString::number(aircraftsDone));
    ui->progressBar->repaint();

    if (aircraftsDone == data->outputSettings.aircraftQuantity) {
        accept();
    }
}
```

На данный момент вычисления происходят, однако информация о прогрессе никак не отрисовывается и не обновляется.

Comment: Не вижу this->moveToThread(calculation);

Comment: Также не вижу, как данные из потока calculation "вываливаются" в объект OutputData, который, замечу, находится в главном потоке.

Comment: @magrif данные валятся в процессе счёта в поле окна ProgressDialog

Comment: В какой момент `moveToThread` должно выполняться?

Comment: Лучше создать отдельный класс, отвечающий за вычисления, и у него в конструкторе создать объект потока и вызвать this->moveToThread(calculation);

Comment: Если дело касается потоков в QT, то обойтись без сигналов и слотов не получится. А если получится, то это равносильно изобретению велосипеда - сигналы и слоты сделаны специально для облегчения работы с потоками.

Comment: В вашем случае сама задумка провоцирует на ошибки т.к. позволяет не потокобезопасное обращение к данным. Как сказано выше лучше создать отдельный класс, переместить в другой поток и организовать общение между потоками сигналами. Если между потоками нужно обменивать большим количеством данных, то можно создать класс, хранящий эти данные и сделать его потокобезопасным при помощи QMutex.

Answer (score 0):

Как и советовали выше, в классе главного окна создал поле потока, в конструкторе окна задается поток и через `connect` сделана связь метода вычислений и старта потока:

```
connect(calculationThread, SIGNAL(started()), outputData, SLOT(calculate()));
```